# Postgres pagination with non-unique keys?

Tags: postgresql, pagination

Suppose I have a table of events with (indexed) columns `id : uuid` and `created : timestamp`.

The `id` column is unique, but the `created` column is not. I would like to walk the table in chronological order using the `created` column.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE created >= $<after> ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 10
```

Here `$<after>` is a template parameter that is taken from the previous query.

Now, I can see two issues with this:

1. Since `created` is not unique, the order will not be fully defined. Perhaps the sort should be `id, created`?
2. Each row should only be on one page, but with this query the last row is always included on the next page.

How should I go about this in Postgres?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM events 
  WHERE created >= $<after> and (id >= $<id> OR created > $<after>)
  ORDER BY created ASC ,id ASC LIMIT 10
```

that way the events each timestamp values will be ordered by id. and you can split pages anywhere.

you can say the same thing this way:

```
SELECT * FROM events 
  WHERE (created,id) >= ($<after>,$<id>)
  ORDER BY created ASC ,id ASC LIMIT 10
```

and for me this produces a slightly better plan.

An index on `(created,id)`  will help performance most, but for
many circumstances an index on `created` may suffice.

Answer (score 0):

First, as you said, you should enforce a total ordering. Since the main thing you care about is `created`, you should start with that. `id` could be the secondary ordering, a tie breaker invisible to the user that just ensures the ordering is consistent. Secondly, instead of messing around with conditions on `created`, you could just use an `offset` clause to return later results:

```
SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY created ASC, id ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET <10 * page number>
-- Note that page number is zero based
```

Comment: The part about including `id` in the ordering is spot on. The part about `OFFSET` should go - it is inefficient to paginate like that, and I think the OP wants to avoid it.